# Calculate age from string swift

Tags: swift, string, date

I am trying to calculate any persons age ranging from infants to adults (e.g 8 weeks old, or 4 months old, or 22 years old). But my calculations are off and I cant find where. If i enter the DOB as 10/16/2020 it returns 8 weeks old which is correct. However if I enter 10/26/2020 it returns 11 weeks old and that is incorrect. Any help is much appreciated.

Age Func:

```
let bornOn = "10/16/2020"
func calculateAge(dob: String, format: String = "MM/dd/yyyy") -> String{
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = format
    let date = df.date(from: dob)
    guard let val = date else{
        return ""
    }
    var years = 0
    var months = 0
    var days = 0
    
    let cal = Calendar.current
    years = cal.component(.year, from: Date()) - cal.component(.year, from: val)
    
    let currentMonth = cal.component(.month, from: Date())
    let birthMonth = cal.component(.month, from: val)
    
    months = currentMonth - birthMonth
    
    if months < 0 {
        years = years - 1
        months = 12 - birthMonth
        if cal.component(.day, from: Date()) < cal.component(.day, from: val){
            months = months - 1
        }
    }else if months == 0 && cal.component(.day, from: Date()) < cal.component(.day, from: val){
        years = years - 1
        months = 11
    }
    if cal.component(.day, from: Date()) > cal.component(.day, from: val){
        days = cal.component(.day, from: Date()) - cal.component(.day, from: val)
    }else if cal.component(.day, from: Date()) < cal.component(.day, from: val){
        let today = cal.component(.day, from: Date())
        let date = cal.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date())
        days = date!.daysInMonth - cal.component(.day, from: val) + today
    }else{
        days = 0
        if months == 12 {
            years = years + 1
            months = 0
        }
    }
    print("Years: \(years), Months: \(months), Days: \(days)")
    if years > 0{
        if years == 1{
            return "\(years) year old"
        }else{
        return "\(years) years old"
        }
    }else if months > 4{
        return "\(months) months old"
    }else {
        if  months >= 1{
            let daysleftInMonth = months * 30
            print(daysleftInMonth)
            days += daysleftInMonth
        }
       
        let weeks = days / 7
       return "\(weeks) weeks old"
    }
}

extension Date{
     var daysInMonth:Int{
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: calendar.component(.year, from: self), month: calendar.component(.month, from: self))
        let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
        
        let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date)!
        let numDays = range.count
        
        return numDays
    }
}
calculateAge(dob: bornOn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going in the wrong direction. What you need is to parse your date string converting it to date and use DateComponentsFormatter to display the person's age. You can also get the date components from the date of birthday until today:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let dateMMddyyyy: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        return formatter
    }()
    static let dateComponents: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .month, .year]
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    var ageComponents: DateComponents { Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self, to: Date()) }
    var relativeAge: String {
        Formatter.dateComponents.allowedUnits = ageComponents.month! >= 2 ?
            [.day, .month, .year] : [.weekOfMonth]
        return Formatter.dateComponents.string(from: self, to: Date())! 
    }
}
```

---

```
extension String {
    var dateFromMMddyyyy: Date? { Formatter.dateMMddyyyy.date(from: self) }
}
```

---

```
"09/10/1970".dateFromMMddyyyy?.relativeAge  // "50 years"
"10/16/2020".dateFromMMddyyyy?.relativeAge  // "2 months"
"10/23/2020".dateFromMMddyyyy?.relativeAge  // "7 weeks"
```

Comment: I think OP has some custom logic for when to display weeks (less than 4 months), but good advice nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension Date {
    func timeAgo() -> String {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .weekOfMonth ,.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropAll
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        return String(format: formatter.string(from: self, to: Date()) ?? "", locale: .current)
    }
}
```

Use above date extension in your method

```
func calculateAge(dob: String, format: String = "MM/dd/yyyy") -> String{
       let df = DateFormatter()
       df.dateFormat = format
       let date = df.date(from: dob)
       return date?.timeAgo() ?? ""
}
```

Use it like,

```
let date = calculateAge(dob: bornOn)
print(date) //print - 2 weeks
```